# White space caused in responsive Twitter Bootstrap view

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am not sure if this white space above the div is caused by a media query or by something in the twitter bootstrap css.

Here is the page at mid view: http://postimg.org/image/gq9dfuuah

Here is my markup for the top section of the page:

```
<div class="page-section intro">

<div class="container">
    <div class="logo"><img src="../../images/logo-2.png" id="backdrop"></div>
   <div class="intro_wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"><span class="pull-right">
            <div class="mockup">
            <img src="../../images/techandall_shadow_series_apple.png" id="backdrop">
            </div>
        </div></span>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <span class="pull-right">
        <div class="saying">Design, Development, Dedication</div>
                <div class="left"><p class="lead center">We are highly experienced in Responsive Web Design, Database-driven websites, Content Management Systems, and Custom Web Applications.</p>
                </div>
            <div class="intro_buttons center-block">
                <div class="center_button">
                    <a href="#" class="scroll-link btn btn-dark" id="contact" data-id="">Get A Quote</a>
                </div>    
            </div>

        </div></span>
     </div>
    </div><!-- feature_wrapper -->
</div><!--/.container-->
```

Comment: Did you check it with eg. Firebug?

Comment: I will do that and get back with you.